# Configuring High Availability for MySQL Router in a MySQL InnoDB Cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-innodb-cluster

I've configured a MySQL InnoDB Cluster for high availability with two servers on a Windows system (Server 1: h01, IP: 10.61, Server 2: h02, IP: 10.71), running smoothly under the cluster name 'H01E.'. When one instance goes down, the other takes charge and becomes primary. Here's my current cluster status:

```
MySQL  h01:3306 ssl  JS > cluster.status();
{
    "clusterName": "H01E",
    "defaultReplicaSet": {
        "name": "default",
        "primary": "h01:3306",
        "ssl": "REQUIRED",
        "status": "OK_NO_TOLERANCE",
        "statusText": "Cluster is NOT tolerant to any failures.",
        "topology": {
            "h01:3306": {
                "address": "h01:3306",
                "memberRole": "PRIMARY",
                "mode": "R/W",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "replicationLag": "applier_queue_applied",
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "ONLINE",
                "version": "8.0.34"
            },
            "h02:3306": {
                "address": "h02:3306",
                "memberRole": "SECONDARY",
                "mode": "R/O",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "replicationLag": "applier_queue_applied",
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "ONLINE",
                "version": "8.0.34"
            }
        },
        "topologyMode": "Single-Primary"
    },
    "groupInformationSourceMember": "h01:3306"
}
```

To enhance the high availability of my setup, I'm now seeking to ensure the availability of my MySQL Router. My objective is to create a robust, high-availability setup by installing a second MySQL Router on the second instance. The aim is to have them work together, monitoring each other's health, and automatically taking over if one router fails. After doing some research, I found a potential solution: clustering the routers together. Here's what I've done so far:

- Ensured that MySQL Routers are correctly installed and running on each instance.
- Configured each router with its own unique configuration file (mysqlrouter.conf).

**First instance**

```
# File automatically generated during MySQL Router bootstrap
[DEFAULT]
logging_folder=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/log
runtime_folder=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/run
data_folder=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/data
keyring_path=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/data/keyring
master_key_path=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/mysqlrouter.key
connect_timeout=5
read_timeout=30
dynamic_state=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/data/state.json
client_ssl_cert=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/data/router-cert.pem
client_ssl_key=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/data/router-key.pem
client_ssl_mode=PREFERRED
server_ssl_mode=AS_CLIENT
server_ssl_verify=DISABLED
unknown_config_option=error

[logger]
level=INFO

[metadata_cache:bootstrap]
cluster_type=gr
router_id=1
user=mysql_router1_zw288y
metadata_cluster=H01E
ttl=0.5
auth_cache_ttl=-1
auth_cache_refresh_interval=2
use_gr_notifications=0


[routing:bootstrap_rw]
bind_address=0.0.0.0
bind_port=6446
destinations=metadata-cache://H01E/?role=PRIMARY
routing_strategy=first-available
protocol=classic

[routing:bootstrap_ro]
bind_address=0.0.0.0
bind_port=6447
destinations=metadata-cache://H01E/?role=SECONDARY
routing_strategy=round-robin-with-fallback
protocol=classic
```

**Second instance**

```
# File automatically generated during MySQL Router bootstrap
[DEFAULT]
logging_folder=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/log
runtime_folder=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/run
data_folder=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/data
keyring_path=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/data/keyring
master_key_path=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/mysqlrouter.key
connect_timeout=5
read_timeout=30
dynamic_state=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/data/state.json
client_ssl_cert=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/data/router-cert.pem
client_ssl_key=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Router/data/router-key.pem
client_ssl_mode=PREFERRED
server_ssl_mode=AS_CLIENT
server_ssl_verify=DISABLED
unknown_config_option=error

[logger]
level=INFO

[metadata_cache:bootstrap]
cluster_type=gr
router_id=2
user=mysql_router2_a5sng6
metadata_cluster=H01E
ttl=0.5
auth_cache_ttl=-1
auth_cache_refresh_interval=2
use_gr_notifications=0

[routing:bootstrap_rw]
bind_address=0.0.0.0
bind_port=6450
destinations=metadata-cache://H01E/?role=PRIMARY
routing_strategy=first-available
protocol=classic

[routing:bootstrap_ro]
bind_address=0.0.0.0
bind_port=6447
destinations=metadata-cache://H01E/?role=SECONDARY
routing_strategy=round-robin-with-fallback
protocol=classic
```

Each router needs a unique 'router_id' and 'user'.

The 'metadata_cluster' in both routers should match the cluster name, which is "H01E."

In the [routing:bootstrap_rw] section, the 'destinations' line should also match the cluster name.

The 'bind_port' in [routing:bootstrap_rw] must be unique port number and not used by other routing sections.

These configurations ensure the routers collaborate effectively to provide high availability for database connections."

Now, I've reached a point where I need to test failover in my setup to check if it's working. But before that, I needed to know which MySQL Router is currently the primary one. To identify the primary router, I used the command “SELECT @@global.read_only”. Here's the problem:

When I connect directly to the MySQL instances without using routers, I correctly see one instance as primary (read-write) and the other as not primary (read-only).

**First Node:**

```sql
MySQL  h01:3306 ssl  SQL > SELECT @@global.read_only;
+--------------------+
| @@global.read_only |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.0003 sec)
```

**Second Node:**

```sql
MySQL  h02:3306 ssl  SQL > SELECT @@global.read_only;
+--------------------+
| @@global.read_only |
+--------------------+
|                  1 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.0004 sec)
```

However, when I connect via the routers (e.g., `h01:6446` for primary and `h02:6450` for secondary), I see both as primary (read-write), which is not the expected behavior.

**First Node:**

```sql
MySQL  h01:6446 ssl  SQL > SELECT @@global.read_only;
+--------------------+
| @@global.read_only |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.0008 sec)
```

**Second Node:**

```sql
MySQL  h02:6450 ssl  SQL > SELECT @@global.read_only;
+--------------------+


| @@global.read_only |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.0005 sec)
```

In a correctly functioning setup, I should observe different results for `@@global.read_only` depending on whether I connect to the primary or secondary router.

What could be causing both routers to appear as primary (read-write) when connected via the routers? Is there a specific step, parameter, or configuration that I might have overlooked, preventing proper failover recognition and primary router identification?

Are there alternative best practices and methods for achieving high availability with MySQL Routers on Windows.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. You should ask on [dba.se]